# Jackson RuntimePermission exception during Recursive Type serialization

Tags: java, jackson, elasticsearch-plugin, jackson-databind

I'm trying to serialize a recursive `Map` with Jackson and getting some `RuntimePermission` access exceptions. Here's the stack trace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers") (through reference chain: java.util.TreeMap["0"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:725)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:643)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3906)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3220)
    at io.zentity.resolution.Job.serializeLoggedQuery(Job.java:138)
    at io.zentity.resolution.Job.traverse(Job.java:1495)
    at io.zentity.resolution.Job.runResolution(Job.java:1563)
    at io.zentity.resolution.Job.run(Job.java:1604)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugin.zentity.ResolutionAction.lambda$prepareRequest$0(ResolutionAction.java:111)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugin.zentity.BaseAction.lambda$wrappedConsumer$0(BaseAction.java:22)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:227)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.tryAllHandlers(RestController.java:309)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:167)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(AbstractHttpServerTransport.java:322)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport.handleIncomingRequest(AbstractHttpServerTransport.java:372)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport.incomingRequest(AbstractHttpServerTransport.java:301)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(Netty4HttpRequestHandler.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(Netty4HttpRequestHandler.java:29)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpPipeliningHandler.channelRead(Netty4HttpPipeliningHandler.java:58)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:326)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:300)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:600)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:554)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1036)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:408)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:2848)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2247)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.getDeclaredFields(ClassUtil.java:1078)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector._findFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:66)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector._findFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:64)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector._findFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:64)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collect(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:41)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collectFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:36)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._fields(AnnotatedClass.java:349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.fields(AnnotatedClass.java:321)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addFields(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:379)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:308)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getJsonValueAccessor(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:196)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findJsonValueAccessor(BasicBeanDescription.java:252)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerByAnnotations(BasicSerializerFactory.java:346)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.buildMapSerializer(BasicSerializerFactory.java:767)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.buildContainerSerializer(BasicSerializerFactory.java:568)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._createSerializer2(BeanSerializerFactory.java:196)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:165)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1388)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1336)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:510)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.PropertySerializerMap.findAndAddSecondarySerializer(PropertySerializerMap.java:90)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer._findAndAddDynamic(MapSerializer.java:1047)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer._findSerializer(MapSerializer.java:1152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:720)
    ... 63 more
```

The recursive type is defined as:

```java
public class FilterTree extends TreeMap<String, FilterTree> {
}
```

The object is being serialized like so:

```java
Map<Integer, FilterTree> tree = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
tree.put(0, new FilterTree());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(tree); // here lies the exception
```

Is there anything that I'm clearly doing wrong?

Comment: Seems your Java program has the security manager enabled and you didn't grant Jackson access to do reflection. Read up on Java's Security Manager to learn how it works, and how to grant access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson library does not have any issues with serializing a recursive data structure.

I am using following jackson libraries

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.8.5'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.5'
```

And i was able to serialize the similar data structure that you provided.
See Code below

```
public class Test {

static class FilterTree extends TreeMap<String, FilterTree> {
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Map<Integer, FilterTree> tree = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    FilterTree childTree = new FilterTree();
    childTree.put("aaa", new FilterTree());
    childTree.put("bbb", new FilterTree());
    childTree.get("bbb").put("ccc", new FilterTree());
    tree.put(0, childTree);


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(tree);
    System.out.println(jsonStr);
}
```

}

The output that i got is

```
{"0":{"aaa":{},"bbb":{"ccc":{}}}}
```

So i dont think that there is any issue in jackson library as such.

From the stack trace that you provided, it seems that you are using some `elastic-search plugin`

Check following

- What version of Jackson are you using?
- Is the jackson library bundled within elastic search plugin - if yes, then does elastic search provides any configuration for Object Mapper or Json serialization?
- The fields being serialized are not private/protected and can be accessed.
- Also in case you are using an older version of elastic search plugin, you can try upgrading the version and see if it resolves the issue or not

I found few similar issues like one reported by you.. Check if they are of any help (although they are little old issues.. from 2017)

- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/347
- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/26872

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the issue is, but it's somewhere in what you've pointed about the jackson/ elasticsearch/ java security integration.